# What if Redis keys are never deleted programmatically?

Tags: redis

What will happen to my redis data if no expiry is set and no DEL command is used.

Will it be removed after some default time ?

One more,
How redis stores data, is it in any file format ? because I can access data even after restarting the computer. So which files are created by redis and where ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis is a in-memory data store meaning all your data is kept in RAM (ie. volatile). So theoritically your data will live as long as you don't turn the power off.

However, it also provides persistence in two modes:

- *RDB* mode which takes snapshots of your dataset and saves them to the disk in a file called `dump.drb`. This is the default mode.
- *AOF mode* which records every write operation executed by the server in an Append-Only file and then replays it thus reconstructing the original data.

Redis persistence is very good explained [here](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) and [here](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html) by the creator of Redis himself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, RDB enabled by default. I will go through second link.